# Holding power button doesn't work on Nexus 4

Tags: nexus-4, buttons

My Nexus 4's power button's hold function is not working. I can lock my screen, but anything which involves me having to hold the power button isn't working.

I'm scared to even wait for my phone to drain all the battery and shut down because I have to hold the power button for it to start. I'm stuck.

Is this a hardware break or a software bug?